# Java.Помогите найти исправить ошибку в парсере на JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

Здравствуйте, мне надо распарсить вот такой `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>
<AddOrder book="book-1" operation="SELL" price="100.50" volume="81" orderId="1" />
<AddOrder book="book-3" operation="BUY" price=" 99.50" volume="86" orderId="2" />
<DeleteOrder book="book-2" orderId="104" />
<AddOrder book="book-1" operation="BUY" price=" 99.70" volume="16" orderId="3" />
<AddOrder book="book-3" operation="SELL" price="100.00" volume="80" orderId="4" />
<DeleteOrder book="book-2" orderId="104" />
<AddOrder book="book-3" operation="SELL" price="100.80" volume="24" orderId="149" />
</Orders>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать это при помощи `JAXB`. Это мое первое знакомство с ним по этому не кидайте помидоры пожалуйста.
Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

Класс заявки:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "AddOrder")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"book","operation","volume","price","orderId"})
public class Order {
    private String book;
    private String operation;
    private int volume;
    private float price;
    private int orderId;

    public String getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setBook(String book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    public String getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setOperation(String operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public int getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setVolume(int volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
}
```

Сам парсер:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.File;

public class JaxbParser implements Parser {
    @Override
    public Object getObject(File file, Class c) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(c);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        return unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    }
}
```

Ну когда я пытаюсь это дело пробовать:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        Parser parser = new JaxbParser();
        File file = new File("/Users/pavel/Desktop/order1.xml");
        Order order = (Order) parser.getObject(file, Order.class);
        System.out.println(order);
    }
```

Все падает с ошибкой:

> unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Orders"). Expected elements are
>   <{}AddOrder>

И я бы подумал что все дело в тэге  в начале файла, но когда я оставил в файле одну строку `<AddOrder book="book-1" operation="SELL" price="100.50" volume="81" orderId="1" />` (все остальное вообще удалил) в качестве эксперимента, то объект конечно создался, но с пустыми полями, то есть данные, так в объект и не записались.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться что я не так делаю. Как мне распарсить этот файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У тебя в xml не один элемент, а коллекция. Даже две.
Надо сделать "Корневой класс", который будет описывать корень xml-ки и загружать через него.

1. Убери из класса Order аннотацию @XmlRootElement(name = "AddOrder")
2. Создай класс Orders

   @XmlRootElement(name = "Orders")
   public class Orders {
       private List addOrders;
       private List deleteOrders;

   ```
   @XmlElement(name = "AddOrder")
   public List<Order> getAddOrders...
   public void setAddOrders...

   @XmlElement(name = "DeleteOrder")
   public List<Order> getDeleteOrders...
   public void setDeleteOrders...
   ```

   }
3. Загружай xml, используя этот класс:

   Orders orders = (Orders) parser.getObject(file, Orders.class);

И еще по поводу каждого ордера:

У тебя тут свойства представлены атрибутами. Следовательно у класса Order геттры и сеттеры свойств надо помечать @XmlAttribute, а не @XmlElement.

Answer (score 2):

1. Опишите схему вашего документа [XML Scheme](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema)
2. При помощи **JAXB Compiler** создайте набор классов
3. Используйте **Unmarshaller**

   ```
   JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("<имя пакета>")
   Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
   Order o = (Order) u.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("<xml файл>"));
   ```

Comment: >>Опишите схему вашего документа<< так а разве не описал в классе Order? Просто даже когда схема документа сводится к одной единственной строке <AddOrder book="book-1" operation="SELL" price="100.50" volume="81" orderId="1" /> код все равно не работает. Вот что меня смущает,скогда я распечатываю объект у меня строки null а примитивы 0. Хотя вроде компилируется.

Comment: схема это xml документ. обычно с расширением xsd. я добавил ссылку в ответ.

Comment: А где размещать файл-схему?

Comment: @Павел не важно где. Она нужна на этапе компиляции.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman ему не надо никаких схем. У него ошибки в аннотациях и класса не хватает. Вместо того, чтобы указать где ошибки, вы предлагаете залезть в болото xsd.